# What would make a Meteor app stop scrolling?

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

Any browser. All other functions operate as normal. I can traverse routes, open modals, dropdowns, manipulate collections... everything works.

But at some point, the *browser will no longer scroll*. In any view. Unless I **refresh** the browser window. Then scrolling goes back to normal.

What might cause this? Why does refreshing the page fix the issue? Is there a method to smack reactivity upside the head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to navigating away from a (Bootstrap ?) modal without properly closing it.

When you show up a modal in HTML5 frameworks, they usualy display a backdrop (some kind of fullscreen grayed out component) and disable scrolling to simulate desktop experience.

You can solve this problem using a simple `iron:router` pattern, if you're not using this package, be sure to execute the corresponding code whenever you navigate away from a page where a modal might get shown.

client/views/modal/modal.html

```
<template name="modal">
  <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<template name="main">
  {{> modal}}
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
    Show Modal
  </button>
</template>
```

client/config/router.js :

```
// define the plugin
Iron.Router.plugins.hideBootstrapModalOnStop=function(router,options){
  router.onStop(function(){
    // hide modal backdrop on route change
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    // remove modal-open state on body
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
  });
};

// activate the plugin
Router.plugin("hideBootstrapModalOnStop");
```

The `.modal-open` class set on the HTML body tag is the one disabling scrolling when it is set, so by making sure that we remove that class whenever we navigate away from a page when a modal is possibly shown, we prevent this weird unexpected behavior to happen.

Comment: Exactly! Wow. You are good. Just figured this out. Turns out there's a Bootstrap event for just such issue:

 `$('#delete-comment').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
      // put your code in here // 
});`

 Thank you!

Comment: This event will only get triggered when you explicitly call `$(".modal").modal("hide")` or when the user discards the modal, but it won't get called when Blaze wipes out the modal HTML via `iron:router`.